# Right way to do this query

Tags: mysql

I have a table

> form (
>       int id ) 
>   webformsystemflags (   int id,   int formid   int sysflagid )
>
> sysflag ( int id, name char(10) )

form table is a table which has all the forms

webform is a table which has the forms which have flags applied to it. It has a foreign key formid which is id to the form table and sysflagid which is foreign key to the sys flag table

sys flag is the table which contains the flags. Lets say I have flags defined as 1,2,3
I can have forms which don't have all the flags applied to it, some may have 1, some may have 2 or some may have 3 applied to it or some may have none.

How can I find all the forms which have either flag 1 or flag 2 or flag 3 applied to it ?

Comment: From looking at the answers provided, and what you do/dont want, which is it.  Do you want to know which form has ANY OF flag 1, 2 3 (one or more).... OR... Are you looking for forms that do NOT have a specific flag. They are totally different queries.

Comment: I'm looking for a form which doesn't have a certain/specific flag applied.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your last comment where it pulls a form that has only 1 applied and not 2 or 3. From that you can tailor your query to find where a form has flag 2 and not 1 or 3 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common trick to find EXCLUSION.  The value I have below of "FlagYouAreExpectingTo_*NOT*_Exist" is explicitly the one you expect NOT to be there.  Here's how it works.

Get every form and LEFT JOIN to the Web System Flags table WITH FINDING the matching form, and flag setting you DO NOT want.  If it finds a valid entry for the form and flag, the "formid" in the (wsf) table will exist.  So, we want all that DON'T exist, hence the closing WHERE wsf.formid is null.

It will be NULL for those where it is NOT already flagged.

```
select
      f.ID
   from
      forms f
         left join webformsystemflags wsf
            on  f.id = wsf.formid
           AND wsf.sysflagid = FlagYouAreExpectingTo__NOT__Exist
   where
      wsf.formid is null
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM `form` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `formid` FROM `webformsystemflags`)
```

Careful with subqueries on huge databases though. You could do the same thing with joins but this is an easy solution that will get you going.

Or for all results that DO NOT have a certain flag:

```
SELECT * FROM `form` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `formid` FROM `webformsystemflags` WHERE `sysflagid` != 1 OR `sysflagid` != 2)
```

or a join method:

```
SELECT f.*, r.`sysflagid` FROM `form` f LEFT JOIN `webformsystemflags` r ON r.`formid` = f.`id` WHERE r.`sysflagid` != null
```

will get you the forms and the related flags. However, it will not get ALL flags in one row if the form has multiple flags on it. That one you may need to do a concat on the flags, but this answer is already growing unnecessarily complex.

**LAST EDIT **

Ok nutsandbolts - You need to update your question cause the two of us have overshot ourselves in a number of different queries and it isn't really helping to come back saying it doesnt give the right results. The right results can easily be reached by simply examining the queries we have provided and using the general logic behind them to compose the query that is right for you.

So my last suggestion - you say you want a query that will return a form **IF** it has a certain flag applied to it **AND** that is does **NOT** have other flags applied to it.

Here it is supposing you wanted all forms with a flag of 1 AND NOT 2 or 3 or none:

```
SELECT f.*, r.`sysflagid` FROM `form` f LEFT JOIN `webformsystemflags` r ON r.`formid` = f.`id` WHERE r.`sysflagid` =1  AND r.`formid` NOT IN (SELECT `formid` FROM `webformsystemflags` WHERE `sysflagid` = 2 OR `sysflagid` = 3)
```

Because your webformsystemflags is relational this query will NOT return any forms that do not exist in the webformsystemflags table - so you don't need to consider null.

If this is not what you're looking for I strongly suggest you rewrite your question with absolute and perfect clarity on your needs cause after this one I'm out of this conversation. Much luck to you though. Have fun.

Comment: This will give me the records which have flag applied. I need the record on which there is a certain flag which is not applied

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `exists` clause to pull records like this:

```
select a.*
from form a
where exists (select 1 
              from webformsystemflags 
              where formid = a.id 
              and sysflagid IN (1,2,3))
```

This won't give you the associated flag.  If you want that:

```
select a.*, b.sysflagid
from form a
join (select formid, sysflagid
           from webformsystemflags
           where sysflagid in (1,2,3)) b
on a.id = b.formid
```

There are many different ways to solve this.

EDIT:  By reading a comment on the other answer it seems the question was unclear.  You want the result forms that only have ONE flag?  i.e. the form has flag 1 but not 2 or 3?

edit2: if you really just want a true/false query pulling only the true (has a flag):

```
select a.*, b.sysflagid
from form a
join webformsystemflags b on a.id = b.formid
```

If you want forms without flags:

```
select a.*
from form a
left join webformsystemflags b on a.id = b.formid
where b.formid is null
```

edit3: Based on comment, forms with one flag and not one of the others:

```
select a.*
from form a
where exists (select 1 from webformsystemflags where formid = a.id and sysflagid = 1)
and (
  not exists (select 1 from webformsystemflags where formid = a.id and sysflagid = 2)
  or
  not exists (select 1 from webformsystemflags where formid = a.id and sysflagid = 3)
)
```

Comment: I'm curious fosco - how does this method's efficiency compare to the basic subquery I mentioned? I myself have never found a need to use the exist clause and it looks syntactically unnecessary. However, it might very well be much more efficient. Do you know? ps - this is not a snide comment I really am curious

Comment: @KaiQing I have been using the `exists` clause for years, it is the right tool for many jobs.  I can't compare to your query at the moment because it does not return the right results.  If you update your answer I may be able to draw some comparison.

Comment: This says any: "How can I find all the forms which have either flag 1 or flag 2 or flag 3 applied to it ? some may have 1, some may have 2 or some may have 3 applied to it or some may have none." the first subquery in my example does return any form that has any flag on it. The question suggests there are only 1 2 or 3, so granted, yes, my example is limited to a true or false and not specific to 1, 2, or 3. If there are an unlimited number of sysformid's then it is inaccurate. But for my question to you, I suppose there is only 1, 2, or 3 for sysflagid.

Comment: Added additional possibilities for this terrible vague question.

Comment: I'm looking for forms which may not have a certain flag applied. All The queries give me in-correct result. I gave an example saying if I have an entry in the table which has flag 1 applied and 2 or 3 not applied, how can I get those ?